# How to use BouncyCastle for C# with non-exportable keys from the Microsoft Software Key Storage Provider?

Tags: c#, windows, bouncycastle

I have an RSA keypair stored in the Microsoft Software Key Storage Provider and marked as non-exportable. I want to sign some data using the private key.

Does BouncyCastle support such functionality? If so, where can I find documentation about it?